# SQL: how to select a single id that meets multiple criteria from multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, search, select, criteria

On a MySQL database, I have the table below

```
package_content :

id | package_id | content_number | content_name | content_quality

1       99           11               Yellow           1
2       99           22               Red              5
3       101          11               Yellow           5
4       101          33               Green            5
5       101          44               Black            5
6       120          11               Yellow           5
7       120          55               White            5
8       135          66               Pink             5
9       135          99               Orange           5
10      135          11               Yellow           5
```

and i am looking a possibility to make search queries on it:

I would like to select the `package_id` where `content_number` could be `11` **AND** `22` (In this case it should select only `package_id 99`

I really don't know if it's possible in SQL since the statement `AND` will always results as false. If i use the statement `OR` i also get the `package_id 99, 101, 120, 135` and that's not what i want.

Maybe my table is not well designed too, but any suggestions would help!
Thanks in advance

**Edit**

I added the `content_quality` column

I used the sql query from juergen, works very well

```
select package_id
from package_content
where content_number in (11,22)
group by package_id
having count(distinct content_number) = 2
```

My last question is how could i now add another criteria : Select the `package_id` where `content_number` is `11` **and** `22` **and** `content_number 11` has `content_quality 1`

**Edit 2:**

For the 2nd question i use now this query. Thanks to both of you who helped me! :)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT package_id
   FROM package_content
   WHERE 
      (content_number=11 AND content_quality > 1)
      OR (content_number = 33 AND content_quality = 5)
      OR (content_number = 44 AND content_quality =5 AND content_name like 'Black')
   GROUP BY package_id
   HAVING count( DISTINCT content_number) = 3
   )t1
LEFT JOIN package_content ON package_content.package_id = t1.package_id
```

This will output

```
id | package_id | content_number | content_name | content_quality

3       101          11               Yellow           5
4       101          33               Green            5
5       101          44               Black            5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to group by the `package_id` and then use `having` to perform an aggregate function over the grouped data

```
select package_id
from package_content
where content_number = 22
or
(
    content_number = 11 and content_quality = 1
)
group by package_id
having count(distinct content_number) = 2
```

Comment: wow! It works fine ! Thx so much. I used your second query, may i ask what the (distinct content_number) = 2 means ? What if i search for 3 number ? Should i then use (distinct content_number) = 3 ?

Comment: Yes you need `3` if you search for 3 numbers. First I filter the data with there `where` clause. Only `content_number`s `11` and `22` remain. Then I use `count(distinct content_number)` to count the number of the remaining `content_number`s. The `distinct` is used to make sure there is not only 2 times `22` but `11` and `22`.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question, how can i now add a new criteria in your query ? With an other where clause and a second having count ?

Comment: I updated my answer. You could remove the parentheses from there `where` clause if you like. I added them for better readability.

Comment: Thank you! As you can see i updated my question with the final query. Have to test it more because i use about 8 criteria in reality. But looks good. If you see something weird, dont hesitate :p Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can't see anything stupid in your query :) Instead of a join you could do: `select * from package_content where package_id in (select package_id from ...)`

Comment: Works also with your solution except i get 0.0015sec instead of 0.0007sec with mine. So i guess i'll stay like that :)

Answer (score 1):

You could query with a self join for that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT package_id
FROM package_content a, package_content b
WHERE a.package_id = b.package_id
      AND a.content_number = 11 AND b.content_number = 22
```

Edit: For your second question: Just add that to the query. The package_content renamed to `a` is responsible for the content_number 11. Therefore you can ask, wether a has content_quality 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT package_id
FROM package_content a, package_content b
WHERE a.package_id = b.package_id
      AND a.content_number = 11 AND b.content_number = 22
      AND a.content_quality = 1
```